# proftpd quota does not work with sftp

Tags: sftp, proftpd

Running into an issue where quota does not work with SFTP users. Regular ftp/tls users are working fine.

Can the mod_quotatab_file.c authenticate SFTP users or is it limited only to regular ftp users?

Modules

```
LoadModule mod_sql.c
LoadModule mod_sql_mysql.c
LoadModule mod_quotatab.c
LoadModule mod_quotatab_file.c
LoadModule mod_ctrls_admin.c
LoadModule mod_exec.c
LoadModule mod_sftp.c
```

SFTP Configs

```
</VirtualHost>

## SFTP CONFIG
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0>
  Port                          2222
  MasqueradeAddress             X.X.X.X

  <IfModule mod_sftp.c>
    Port 2222
    ##SFTP
    SFTPEngine    on
    SFTPLog       /var/log/proftpd/sftp.log
    TransferLog   /var/log/proftpd/sftp-xferlog
    SFTPHostKey   /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
    SFTPHostKey   /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
    SFTPOptions   IgnoreSFTPUploadPerms
    #DenyUser      sftpOnlyUser
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

Quota Configs

```
## QUOTA CONFIG
<IfModule mod_quotatab_file.c>
  QuotaEngine on
  QuotaLog /var/log/proftpd/quota.log
  QuotaOptions ScanOnLogin
  QuotaDirectoryTally off
  QuotaDisplayUnits Mb

  # Unit is in byte
  QuotaDefault user false hard 5242880 5242880 0 0 0 0

  <IfModule mod_quotatab_file.c>
    QuotaLimitTable file:/efs/ftpquota.limittab
    QuotaTallyTable file:/efs/ftpquota.tallytab
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added QUOTA CONFIG under Global settings and sftp started picking up the quota.